# PayPal webhook created vs activated

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-webhooks

I'm finishing up my paypal webhook, when dealing with subscriptions is their a difference between `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED` and `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED`?

When looking at the the [developer docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#authorized-and-captured-payments) it doesn't say anything except `A subscription is activated` and `A subscription is created` which doesn't say if there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

A subscription must necessarily be created before it can be activated, you can't activate a nonexistent subscription.

A subscription can be suspended and activated again.

Comment: Fair enough, so i wouldn't necessarily have to do anything with a created webhook on the server side?

Comment: Not necessarily, but possibly. It depends on how you are having the user approve the subscription and what the `user_action` is. The default is to activate the subscription when approved.